# Is possible to use IBM DB2 with JRuby on rails?

Tags: db2, jruby, adapter, jrubyonrails

In DB2 Version 9.7 is said:

> The IBM_DB Ruby driver and Rails adapter are not supported on JRuby
>   The IBM_DB adapter is not supported on JRuby.
>
> The IBM_DB adapter is not supported on JRuby because (as stated in the
>   JRuby Wiki, "Getting Started"): "Many Gems will work fine in JRuby,
>   however some Gems build native C libraries as part of their install
>   process. These Gems will not work in JRuby unless the Gem has also
>   provided a Java equivalent to the native library." For more
>   information, see http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/GettingStarted.
>
> The IBM_DB adapter relies on the IBM_DB Ruby driver (C extension) and
>   the IBM® Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI to access databases on
>   IBM data servers. Alternatively, you can either use the regular C
>   implementation of Ruby, or use JDBC_adapter to access databases.

Has anyone knew if this is fixed in the new versions?Also, is it possible to use JDBC_adapter with JRuby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't test it but, according to this https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter

Activerecord-jdbc-adapter is a database adapter for Rails’ ActiveRecord component that can be used with JRuby. It allows use of virtually any JDBC-compliant database with your JRuby on Rails application.

And the corresponding gem has a Java version. https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/versions/1.0.3-java

Regarding your other question, if IBM_DB is fixed in the new versions?

Ithink is not, according to the documentation until JRuby and ActiveRecord-JDBC adapter ripen it wont work.

I found and IBM docummentation that says that can be consider an arrangement in ActiveRecord-JDBC adapter, which can emulate the previous administration providing IBM_DB adapter.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.ruby.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0052771.html